# Laravel error when using Route::resources('book', 'BookController');

Tags: laravel-5

Super new to laravel .So I put Route::resources('books','BookController');
in my web.php but [I am getting an error in my terminal (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNJ5d.png)

also when i run my local host [I get something similar (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxY46.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::resource('resource', 'Controller');
```

`resource` not `resources`, `resources` would be for setting up multiple resources at one go:

```
Route::resources([
    'something' => 'SomethingController',
    'resource' => 'ResourceController',
]);
```

[Laravel 5.5 - Docs- Controllers - Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: thanks , it seems like that works but do we have to manually populate the methods of BookController ? like index (), create()...etc

Answer (score 1):

Do Like this

```
Route::resource('itemCRUD','ItemCRUDController');
```

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/crud-create-read-update-delete-example-in-laravel-52-from-scratchexample.html

Comment: this example will help you

Comment: based on that tutorial this Route::resource('itemCRUD','ItemCRUDController'); is used in app/Http/routes.php but I think it goes in web.php ? right .